# Inheritance and Methods in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

```
  public class TestBoss {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
                  Worker duck = new Worker();

                  (Boss) duck.type();
       }

 public class Boss{
       //stuff
 }

 public class Worker extends Boss{
       public void type(){
        //stuff
       }
 }
```

If there was a superclass called boss and a subclass called worker. So if there was a test class that needed to use a method in the worker class. The object duck in this case is type casted into Boss/ In the code though, the type method is only usable in the worker class and not in the boss class. however java requires that Boss class contains the type method even though it's not used. How does one make the method declared only in the worker class or does boss class need to have a filler method that essentially does nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface. Make `Worker` implementing that interface, but not `Boss`.

```
 public class Worker extends Boss implements YourInterface
 {
  ...
 }

 interface YourInterface
 {
       public void type();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If only `Worker` exposes the method `type()` then you need to cast your object back to `Worker` before you can use it. E.g.

```
Worker duck = new Worker();
...
Boss boss = (Boss)duck;
...
if (boss instanceof Worker) // check in case you don't know 100% if boss is actually a worker
{
    (Worker)boss.type();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what does `Boss boss = (Boss)worker;` mean here? Without creating a `worker` instance you can cast it eh? Please elucidate.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was supposed to be Boss boss = (Boss)duck;

Comment: Aah, it was a typo. Lol, I thought it was something which I didn't know and could learn :P

Answer (score 1):

This is basic principal of `OOP`.. **You can call Only those method  with parents reference , which is exist in Parent..**

```
Boss boss=new Worker();
```

using `boss` u call only method which is exist in Boss coz at time of completion method existence check in parent class in above case..

So You have only 2 way to call a personal method of child class..
**1st :-** create same method in your parent. Parent may be `interface or class` like **deporter** said.
**2nd :-** Or `downcast` it into your child class..

```
(Worker)boss.type();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
 public class TestBoss {

          public static void main(String[] args) {
Boss duck = new Worker();
                      ((Worker) duck).type();
           }

     public class Boss{
           //stuff
     }

     public class Worker extends Boss{
           public void type(){
            //stuff
           }
     }
```